# want to pipe while read find thru shuf util

Tags: bash, shuffle

I currently use this as input for a random song selector:

```
done < <(sort -zuR <(find "$dir" -type f \( -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.ogg' \) -print0))
```

but I have noticed often that I get songs from the same album in what I consider to be a rather large music catalogue. Anyways I wanted to try and pipe thru 'shuf' to see if I notice any difference, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I tried what I felt was obvious:

```
done < <(shuf <(find "$dir" -type f \( -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.ogg' \) -print0))
```

and then:

```
done < <(find "$dir" -type f \( -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.ogg' \) -print0|shuf)
```

and this just in case:

```
done < <(find "$dir" -type f \( -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.ogg' \)|shuf)
```

but so far no love.

But when I create an array like this and walk thru the elements with a 'for' loop the pipe to 'shuf' seems to work fine:

```
trksShuf=($(find "$dir" -type f \( -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.ogg' \)|shuf)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't write how your attempts fail for you, but a quick look into the `shuf(1)` manual suggests using its `-z` switch to adapt it to the `NUL`-separated input.

Comment: that did it: done < <(shuf -z <(find "$dir" -type f \( -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.ogg' \) -print0)) works. I thought the -print 0 in the find command handled the 0 byte line ends. Thanks.

Comment: @nanker Well `find ... -print0` produces `NUL`-separated output, but you still need to tell `shuf` that its input is `NUL`-separated.